# c++ checkbox color

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox

In Visual Studio 2010 I have made a checkbox (IDC_CHECK1) in the resource designer. But unfortunately it looks like this on black background: [image]

I couldn't find any options in the properties menu to change the background color or at least make it to transparent. Is there any way to do this in resource designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to handle the WM_CTLCOLORBTN message in your DlgProc.

Comment: Solution is this:

   case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
            static HBRUSH hBrushColor;

                if (!hBrushColor) {
                    hBrushColor = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)); 
                    SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0, 0, 0));          
                }

                return (LRESULT)hBrushColor;
        }

Thank you! :D

Comment: Note: if you want to play around with colours that way, make sure that non element at all uses the colour from the desktop theme. If not things may be impossible to read.

Comment: Also: `If the application returns a brush that it created (for example, by using the CreateSolidBrush or CreateBrushIndirect function), the application must free the brush. If the application returns a system brush (for example, one that was retrieved by the GetStockObject or GetSysColorBrush function), the application does not need to free the brush.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx